# C# Randomize inherited class without hardcoding

Tags: c#, polymorphism

What I want to achieve is to by either name of derived class or enum name generate a random derived class. While my code works in this case, it will require a lot of hardcoding if i decide to expand on it and to me it seems like a bad solution.

Here is my example code: (the UnitTypes variable includes all derived class names dynamically, so i feel like it may be useful - but I could figure out how to.)

```
public void Run()
        {

            var UnitTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(Unit));
            Unit NewMonster = new Unit(); //<---

        konny: //for testing things out.

            int RandomType = new Random().Next(0, UnitTypes.Count());

            switch (RandomType)
            {
                case 0:
                    NewMonster = new Dingo();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    NewMonster = new Buffalo();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    NewMonster = new Dog();
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"A wild {NewMonster.Name} appears");
            NewMonster.Attack();
            Console.ReadLine();

            goto konny;            
        }
```

And the Baseclass + 1 derived for sake of example.

```
    public class Unit
    {
        public Enemies Name { get; set; }

        public enum Enemies
        {
            Dingo, Buffalo, Dog
        }

        public virtual void Attack()
        {
            //nothing to see here
        }
   
    }

    class Dingo : Unit
    {

        public Dingo()
        {
            Name = Enemies.Dingo;
        }

        public override void Attack()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name}  gnaws at your brain");
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can create an array of types (`var types = new [] {typeof(A), typeof(B) /* , ... */};`) or even an array of typenames (as strings) and use `Activator.CreateInstance` to construct instances.  You'll still have to create the classes.  Consider making the Name property as an abstract _getter_ in the base class.  Then the subclasses don't need constructors, but they do need to implement the getter: `public override Enemies Name => Enemies.Dingo;`

Comment: Not my down vote, but it may be because you posted working code that you want to refactor versus having code that doesn't work and you are trying to get working. Your  question may be worth posting to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: alright, I will keep that in mind for future questions @quaabamm. I'm an infrequent user of this site, also am unbothered with internet polarizing metrics (but that's another topic) - so downvotes are OK!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this.  First create a base class (I have no idea why you named it `Unit`, I named mine BaseAnimal):

```
namespace AnimalsTest
{
    public abstract class BaseAnimal
    {    
        public enum EnemiesTypes
        {
            Dingo, Buffalo, Dog
        }

        public abstract IEnumerable<EnemiesTypes> Enemies { get; }

        public abstract void Attack();
    }
}
```

Note that it's an `abstract` (non-instantiable) and that any sub-classes need to implement an `Enemies` property getter and an `Attack` method.

Then I created three subclasses (in the same namespace):

```
class Dingo : BaseAnimal
{
    public override IEnumerable<EnemiesTypes> Enemies =>
        new List<EnemiesTypes> { EnemiesTypes.Buffalo, EnemiesTypes.Dog };

    public override void Attack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(Dingo)} Gnaws at your brain");
    }
}

class Buffalo : BaseAnimal
{
    public override IEnumerable<EnemiesTypes> Enemies =>
        new List<EnemiesTypes> { EnemiesTypes.Dog };

    public override void Attack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(Buffalo)} Runs you down");
    }
}

class Dog : BaseAnimal
{
    public override IEnumerable<EnemiesTypes> Enemies =>
        new List<EnemiesTypes> { EnemiesTypes.Buffalo };

    public override void Attack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(Dog)} Barks at you");
    }
}
```

These are very simple classes, you could make them more complicated.

Finally a test routine that exercises what I think you want.  I get the names of the classes from the values of an `enum` and instantiate them at will.

```
private static readonly Random Random = new Random();
public static void Test()
{
    var animalClasses = Enum.GetNames(typeof(EnemiesTypes)).Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray();
    var thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;

    for (var i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        var className = nameof(AnimalsTest) + "." + animalClasses[Random.Next(0, animalClasses.Length)];
        var animal = (BaseAnimal) Activator.CreateInstance(thisAssembly, className).Unwrap();
        animal.Attack();
        Console.WriteLine($"{animal.GetType().Name} has enemies: {string.Join(", ",animal.Enemies.Select(e=>e.ToString()))}");
        Console.WriteLine();
        ;
    }
}
```

Note that the test code has no clue about the names of the classes it's working with, it pulls it all from the values of the enum.

Each time I run this, I get a different result (because of, well, `Random`).  But, here's the output of a typical run:

```
Buffalo Runs you down
Buffalo has enemies: Dog

Dog Barks at you
Dog has enemies: Buffalo

Buffalo Runs you down
Buffalo has enemies: Dog

Dog Barks at you
Dog has enemies: Buffalo

Dingo Gnaws at your brain
Dingo has enemies: Buffalo, Dog

Dingo Gnaws at your brain
Dingo has enemies: Buffalo, Dog
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly what I was looking for and more. The Unit name was intended for both players + enemies eventually (but perhaps its a poor choice even if that would be the case).